# Apache airflow: Cannot use more than 1 thread when using sqlite. Setting max_threads to 1

Tags: multithreading, postgresql, sqlite, airflow

I have setup airflow with postgresql database, I am creating multiple dags

```
def subdag(parent_dag_name, child_dag_name,currentDate,batchId,category,subCategory,yearMonth,utilityType,REALTIME_HOME, args):
dag_subdag = DAG(
    dag_id='%s.%s' % (parent_dag_name, child_dag_name),
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval="@once",
)
# get site list to run bs reports
site_list = getSiteListforProcessing(category,subCategory,utilityType,yearMonth);
print (site_list)
def update_status(siteId,**kwargs):
    createdDate=getCurrentTimestamp();
    print ('N',siteId,batchId,yearMonth,utilityType,'N')
    updateJobStatusLog('N',siteId,batchId,yearMonth,utilityType,'P')

def error_status(siteId,**kwargs):
    createdDate=getCurrentTimestamp();
    print ('N',siteId,batchId,yearMonth,utilityType,'N')

BS_template = """
echo "{{ params.date }}"
java -cp xx.jar com.xGenerator {{params.siteId}} {{params.utilityType}} {{params.date}}
"""

for index,siteid in enumerate(site_list):
    t1 = BashOperator(
            task_id='%s-task-%s' % (child_dag_name, index + 1),
            bash_command=BS_template,
            params={'date':  currentDate, 'realtime_home': REALTIME_HOME,'siteId': siteid, "utilityType":utilityType},
            default_args=args,
            dag=dag_subdag)
    t2 = PythonOperator(
            task_id='%s-updatetask-%s' % (child_dag_name, index + 1),
            dag=dag_subdag,
            python_callable=update_status,
            op_kwargs={'siteId':siteid})

    t2.set_upstream(t1)
return dag_subdag
```

It creates dynamic tasks but on all number of dynamic task, it always fails the last one and logs error as:
"Cannot use more than 1 thread when using sqlite. Setting max_threads to 1"
E.g. : if 4 tasks are created 3 runs, and if 2 tasks are created 1 runs.

Comment: The "Cannot use more than 1 thread when using sqlite" message isn't really an error, it's just included in the output as it is logged from the settings module. Is there other information in the task logs? What's the state of the "last" task? Failed?

Comment: Can you share your `airflow.cfg`?